# Making a variable based on a string in a dictionary python

Tags: python

I want to create a variable based on the dictionary key. However the key can be anything, so I want the variable name to match that of the key.

For example:

```
>>> dictA = {'foo': 5, 'abc' : 2}
```

I want to have a variable such that.

```
>>> print foo
5
```

Comment: Don't do that, creating variables dynamically is not a good idea. http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html

Answer (score 4):

```
print dictA['foo']
```

or

```
foo = dictA['foo']
print(foo)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically create variables based on your dictionary's keys like this, using `exec` statement **(as long as the key is a valid python variable name)**. Read more about `exec` [here](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-exec-statement).

**Method 1**

```
dictA = {'foo': 5, 'abc' : 2}

for variable, value in dictA.items():
    exec(variable + " = " + str(value))

print foo, abc
```

**Output**

```
5 2
```

**Method 2**

**NOTE:** This works when the code is not inside any functions.

```
for variable, value in dictA.items():
    locals()[variable] = value
```

Or

```
globals().update(dictA) # Suggestion by martineau in the comments
```

**Method 1 is very dangerous.** Consider the `dictA` as this.

```
dictA = {'foo': 5, 'abc' : '__import__("os").unlink("/etc/hosts")'}
```

`exec` will execute the value of `abc` and then assign the value to the variable `abc`. Result: If this was executed as a privileged user, you ll lose `/etc/hosts` file.

**Recommendation**

Use neither of them. They both are hackish ways. Use `dict` as it is. See @Tommy's answer.

Comment: OP say's "the key can be anything" therefore your solution could err in plenty of cases. `{1:1}`

Comment: Regarding **Method 2**: The [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=locals#locals) clear states "**Note** The contents of this dictionary should not be modified; changes may not affect the values of local and free variables used by the interpreter."

Comment: You can't modify `locals` in CPython. You _can_ modify `globals` (and thus `locals` in any scope where both are the same), but your recommendation still stands - don't to this if you don't have a really good reason.

Comment: @martineau I am sorry. Could you please explain that to me? And, when I tried it on my machine, I could see that variables created in `locals()` and `print` was able to print their values.

Comment: @thefourtheye read my comment. What this means is __you cannot modify `locals`__, at least not anywhere where `locals` evaluates to somethin else than `globals` - e.g. inside of a function. You've tried this at the toplevel of the interpreter where `locals==globals`, so what you actually did was modifying `globals`. And the reason why you can't modify `locals` is that a function's local variables are part of the function code object for performance reasons, and thus must be known at compile time.

Comment: @l4mpi Got it :) Thanks. Updated my answer with a note.

Comment: It would be safer to do `globals()[variable] = value` in the loop of Method 1 -- or even simpler, do everything at once with a single line: `globals().update(dictA)`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use `exec()`:

```
for i in dictA:
    exec(i+'='+str(dictA[i]))
```

However, as hcwhsa said, it's really not recommended to create variables dynamically. It can cause a lot of problems, and executing a code from string is also very insecure.

Comment: `TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects`

Comment: Ouch sorry. Fixed that.